# Retrieve all the values from an sqlite table for a specific column whose name is given via user input

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

When I hard-code in which column I want to retrieve all the values from, it works fine, but when using the variable that is passed in by the user it just fills the list with whatever the user input is.

This prints what I want (hard-coded column name)

```
@client.command(aliases=['move'])
async def search_by_move(ctx, *, move):
move_data = [data[0] for data in cursor.execute("SELECT Nair FROM ssbuData")]
    print(move_data)
```

When using the input as a column name, it just fills the list with the input in every index

```
@client.command(aliases=['move'])
async def search_by_move(ctx, *, move):
move_data = [data[0] for data in cursor.execute("SELECT (?) FROM ssbuData", (move,))]
    print(move_data)
```

Results:

['Nair', 'Nair', 'Nair', 'Nair', 'Nair', 'Nair', 'Nair', 'Nair'...]

Desired Results (the ones I get with a hard-coded column name:

['45.0', '38.0', '38.0', '45.0', '45.0', '44.0', '54.0', '38.0'...]

Comment: You can't use parameters for table or column names. Identifiers like that have to be directly present in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding a solution. I did this to insert the variable instead and it works. I'm not entirely sure why this works and the other method of using the variable doesn't for this specific scenario, so if anyone who stumbles upon this could explain that would be great!
Use This:

```
move_data = [data[0] for data in cursor.execute("SELECT {} FROM ssbuData".format(movestr))]
```